# Chrome Extension Query : Related to Content Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, manifest.json

Here is a code snippet from my Manifest.json :

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches" : ["*://www.google.co.in/flights/*"],
        "js" : ["myScript.js"]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
 "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>",
    "*://www.google.co.in/flights/*",
    "tabs"
   ]
```

/* myScript.js */

```
console.debug("Hi I am Content JS");
```

Now if i go to google flights page and open developer tool box then in console section shouldn't I see the above console.debug() message.
I am not getting it where am I going wrong.

Comment: The new chrome doesn't show debug messages by default in the console. Switch the console filter in its toolbar to `verbose`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you.